# how to call java overrided method in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, azure, methods

I want to use my java method on jsp page, but most of answers from stackoverflow is not helpful for me. can someone help me out with this?

```
public class send{
private static final String connectionString = "HostName=hackhubdeu.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=****;SharedAccessKey=****";
private static final IotHubServiceClientProtocol protocol = IotHubServiceClientProtocol.AMQPS;
private static final String deviceId = "hack01";
ServiceClient serviceClient;
boolean onOff = false;



public send() {
    try {
        this.serviceClient = ServiceClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString, protocol);

       this.serviceClient.open();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    messagesending();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new send();

}

public void messagesending() {
    onOff = !onOff;
    try {
        FeedbackReceiver feedbackReceiver = serviceClient.getFeedbackReceiver();
        feedbackReceiver.open();

        Message msg = new Message(String.valueOf(onOff));
        msg.setDeliveryAcknowledgement(DeliveryAcknowledgement.Full);

        serviceClient.send(deviceId, msg);
        System.out.println("Message sent to device");

        FeedbackBatch feedbackBatch = feedbackReceiver.receive(10000);
        if (feedbackBatch != null) {
            System.out.println("Message feedback received, feedback time: "
                    + feedbackBatch.getEnqueuedTimeUtc().toString());
        }
        if (feedbackReceiver != null) feedbackReceiver.close();

    } catch (IotHubException ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException eee) {
        eee.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException eeee) {
        eeee.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

this is my java code, and what i want to call is that public send() method to connect on the serviceclient first, and than call the messagesending() method to do some jobs.

```
<%@page import="munjuPrj.send"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page import ="munjuPrj.send" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
send sendclass = new send();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my jsp code. it doesnt make any error before run, but after i run this code, i get below error:

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /NewFile.jsp at line 14
>   this error code

Comment: Pls change your shared access key immediately. It was exposed..

Comment: Does your program work when you run the send class directly, i mean without making call to JSP page?

Comment: Could you post your Exception StackTrace log to specify the Http status 500 error information?

Answer (score 0):

> what i wanna call is that public send() method to connect on the serviceclient first, and than call the messagesending() method to do some jobs done.

The send() method in your class is not a normal method, its a constructor because its name match with the class name. A constructor is called at object construction time automatically. Thats why when you create new object of send class in JSP, the send() method is called automatically.

If you want to call the send method expilcitly i.e. after making the send object, as you asked. There are two ways:

1. Do not call messagesending() from send() method and update you JSP to make call to messagesending() explicitly. As follows:

   ```
   <% 
   send sendclass = new send();    
   sendclass.messagesending();
   %>
   ```
2. Change you class name from send to MessageSender (but do not change the send() method name and its body). Then write you JSP as follows:

   ```
   <% 
   MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
   messageSender.send();
   %>
   ```

It shall help you to call the send method as you want. The 500 error code shows that was some error at server side while processing the JSP page.